# How to mount btrfs partition?

Tags: mount, raspberry-pi, btrfs, sd-card, xbmc

I've installed xbian distro on RPi.

I want to edit the files in my SD card using my computer, Ubuntu 14.04.

However, when I insert the SD card, the Ubuntu cannot mount the Xbian partition, and gives the following error:

[image: Error: Unable to mount xbian partition]

and when I type `dmesg | tail`  , it gives the following:

[image: Error Messages]

Now what should I do to access the contents of xbian partition on SD card!?

Comment: If at all possible, please copy & paste terminal contents (use "code block" formatting), instead of images. Text is searchable; images are not (at least, not by the search here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd appear you're using a compression algorithm that has been patched in to the Xbian kernel, but not the Ubuntu kernel. It looks like Xbian [patched in and defaulted to lv4](http://forum.xbian.org/thread-2217.html).

That patch hasn't made it to the mainline kernel (see, e.g., [[1]](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/btrfs/ctree.h#n513) and [[2]](https://www.mail-archive.com/linux-btrfs@vger.kernel.org/msg34357.html).) So you'd probably have to rebuild your Ubuntu kernel with the Xbian LZ4 patch (the only way you wouldn't is if someone else has already done it, and you just download/install it).

It looks like you can find the LZ4 patch [at the Xbian kernel github](https://github.com/xbianonpi/xbian-package-kernel/tree/master/patches). Look inside the version matching your kernel version for `lz4.patch`.

Comment: @mchid Nope, that won't add it to the kernel. It's the in-kernel btrfs code that can't handle the LZ4 compression.

Comment: Thanks @derobert for your detailed reply. Actually, I'm new to linux, and I don't know how to do all these stuff! Is there any other alternative to access the contents of this SD card?

Comment: @Omid1989 I think the only other ways are things like boot up the Pi (or whatever) from the SD card, and set it up as an NFS server. Or recreate the filesystem without that compression option. (Note recreating the filesystem deletes all the data on it.)

Comment: Thanks @derobert for your help. It seems that currently the only way to access btrfs/lz4 partition of Xbian is through another Xbian machine!!